# Updating the boolean value of an inequality without having rewrite it

Tags: python, boolean, inequality

I have this simple piece of code:

```
a,b = 1,3
cond = b>a
for i in range(3):
    a+=1
    print("a:",a,"b:",b,"cond:",cond)
```

The result is:

```
a: 2 b: 3 cond: True
a: 3 b: 3 cond: True
a: 4 b: 3 cond: True
```

But we see that at the last iteration, cond should be False. Is there a way to have a boolean value based on an inequality between variables get updated without having to rewrite it at every iteration?

Comment: why should it be false? `cond` never gets updated, so why would you expect its value to change?

Comment: A variable assignment evaluates the expression *at that point*. It is not like putting a formula in a spreadsheet cell.

Answer (score 2):

Make `cond` a function, and call it to evaluate the condition.

```
a, b = 1, 3

def cond():
    return b > a

for _ in range(3):
    a += 1
    print("a:",a,"b:",b,"cond:",cond())
```